# What caused Hide's stomach wound?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Like the title says, what caused Hide's stomach wound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the anime version, which is different from the manga version.

Although it was not shown on screen, it is **highly** suggested that Hideyoshi was caught in the fight between [Seidou Takizawa](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tokyoghoul/images/b/b4/Seidou_Takizawa_anime_design_front_view.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/282?cb=20141227001608) and the ghoul [Noro](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Noro). In fact, we last time we see Hide before he meets Kaneki, he had been noticed by Noro right after he ate Takizawa's arm.